# If $S^1$ were simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose—hypothetically—that $S^1$ were simply connected (it’s not). Under
this assumption prove that any path connected space $X$ would have $π_1(X)=\{0\}$. 
I have no idea. How can I prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to write Henning's argument is to note that, given a loop $\gamma \colon S^1 \rightarrow X$, we have an induced map between the fundamental groups $\gamma_{*} \colon \pi_1(S^1,z_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X,\gamma(z_0))$. The image under $\gamma_{*}$ of the identity loop $\alpha \colon S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is precisely $\gamma$ (namely, $\gamma_{*}([\alpha]) = [\gamma \circ \alpha] = [\gamma]$). If $\pi_1(S^1,z_0)$ is trivial, then $\gamma_{*}([\alpha]) = [\gamma]$ is the identity element of $\pi_1(X,\gamma(z_0))$ and so $\gamma$ is homotopic (in $X$) to a constant loop.

Comment: @DomenicoVuono: I have no idea what you're asking in the first question and the second question follows immediately from the definitions.

Comment: Thanks... After many days I understand.... I'm happy

Answer (score 7):

$\pi_1(X)$ is trivial iff every closed loop is contractible. However, a closed loop is exactly a continuous image of $S_1$, so if we had a contraction of the standard closed loop in $S_1$ that stayed within $S_1$, we could push that forward to contract any closed loop in any space.